# Jackson deserializing custom classes in an OSGi environment

Tags: osgi, jackson, classloader

I have some trouble using Jackson 2.1 in an OSGi environment, when deserializing a class that way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class);

class User {
  public Class clazz = org.example.MyClass.class;
}
```

Because Jackson is in a different bundle as my custom classes I want to deserialize, I often get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` - usually on MyClass1 or MyClass2.

I traced it back to the class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil` which uses `Class.forName(..)` for retrieving a class for deserializing. Because of the different class-loaders on OSGI it only sees the classes of the JRE and of Jackson but not my custom classes.

Is there a simple way to make Jackson find all the required custom classes (I have dozens of them), e.g by adding a class-loader?

Comment: Are you exporting the package where your class resides ?

Comment: Yes, the package is exported but that does not matter as the Jackson bundle does not import it...

Answer (score 4):

As the client of Jackson you have visibility of the classes that you want to deserialize into. The trick is to pass these classes into Jackson, rather than force Jackson to use dynamic reflection to find the classes.

The [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) indicates that the method `ObjectMapper.readValue` can take a `Class` object as its parameter. If you use this method then Jackson should not need to call `Class.forName()`. The docs give the following example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class);
```

Here, `User` is the domain class which is visible to your client but not to Jackson. This invocation should work fine in OSGi... if it does *not* then I would suggest Jackson may have a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already use this variant as it is the standard for deserializing JSON into a class instance. In my case User.class has several fields using other own classes - as I wrote I have dozens of them. For those other classes Jackson always uses dynamic reflection :(

Comment: Then it seems that this should be reported as a bug in Jackson. There is absolutely *no* need for them to resort to loading classes by name. All the required classes are available from reflection using the "root" class you are deserialising into.

Comment: However as a temporary workaround, you may be able to use the Thread context classloader. Try setting the context loader to the value of `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`, where `this` is your client object.

Comment: Thanks, using setContextClassLoader(..) helped me a lot. Anyway I still hope to find a different solution similar to option 1-3 of your [blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html).